# trouble outputting lines from .txt file using while loop, every word of txt file begins on new line

Tags: c++

every word of txt file starts on new line

ex:

first name

last name

first part of phone number

second part of phone number

first part of address

etc..

it should look like:

name

phone number

address

city, state zip

```
int main()
{
string username, streetAddress, city, state, phoneNum, zip;

ofstream outputFile;
outputFile.open("list.txt");

cout << "Enter your name: ";
getline(cin, username);
outputFile << username << endl;

cout << "Enter your phone number: ";
getline(cin, phoneNum);
outputFile << phoneNum << endl;

cout << "Enter street address: ";
getline(cin, streetAddress);
outputFile << streetAddress << endl;

cout << "Enter your city: ";
getline(cin, city);
outputFile << city << ", ";

cout << "Enter your state: ";
getline(cin, state);
outputFile << state << ", ";

cout << "Enter your zip code: ";
getline(cin, zip);
outputFile << zip;

outputFile.close();

ifstream inputFile;
string list;

inputFile.open("list.txt");

while (inputFile >> list) {
    cout << list << endl;
}

inputFile.close();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: std::getline is your savior

Comment: `inputFile >> list` reads one word at a time.

Comment: @QuitePlatypus123 the `>>` operator in C++ normally reads from the left hand side until there is some form of whitespace, then stops. This means that when there's a space in the input, you'll get separate values read in. `std::getline()` is written to continue reading until it finds a line break, so it will not stop when it finds a space.

Comment: right! dumb mistake thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getline` not `>>`

```
while (getline(inputFile, list)) {
    cout << list << endl;
}
```

Your version reads a word at a time, and then outputs each word on a separate line.